# Manipulate the text of a command line argument

Tags: bash

I need to cut some characters from the front of a command line argument. From what I understand I would need to use echo and cut commands together.

So, In brief I have a string of characters and I need to pass it into a command after cutting characters off the front of it.

How can I do this in one line?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it with the Parameter Expansion operators. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

this could be done using the following echo and cut commands

```
str="Some string of characters" 

echo "$str" | cut -c 5-
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
string="hello world"
prefix="hel"
$(echo "$string" | sed -e "s/^$prefix//")
```

It will run the command "lo world"